# importing root CA certificate in linux

Tags: debian, certificates

Maybe this is a duplicate, but i cannot find the answer. Windows CA authorities provide their root certificates in several forms:
The certificate by itself and full chain, each can be downloaded in 2 formats: DER and BASE64. There are tens of articles about certificate formats on the internet but none about what format do I need when I want to import the CA into linux store using `update-ca-certificates`.

The issue is so complicated because not only that there are multiple formats, there are also multiple extensions. In the common case they would be `p7b`, `pem`, `pfx`, `cer` and `crt` and who knows what else. I don't give a damn about understanding all the various "my toy, your toy" psychology of evolution of these formats or their intricacies.

**Can someone simply state:**

1. What format of CA certificate does `update-ca-certificates` requires?
2. What extension does `update-ca-certificates` requires?
3. Which format from Windows CA should I use: DER or Base64 for to get the    certificate and how to convert it to the format understood by `update-ca-certificates`?
4. Should I download the whole chain or just the root CA certificate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

format = Pem file

To convert the certificate, use:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in yourdownloaded.crt -out outcert.pem -text
```

**System**

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
sudo cp root.cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/root.cert.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```